# Embedding Into Tab Bar Controller Offsets Table View

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xcode6.1

I have a View Controller and inside was a Table View and a Navigation Item. Everything was displaying fine until I embedded it into a Tab Bar Controller. Now the Table View is offset underneath the navigation item. I have tried updating frames, updating constraints, resetting to suggested constraints, and manually adjusting the constrains, but none of that has worked yet. What can I do to solve this problem? Below are two images for reference.

[image: Table View Offset under Navigation Item]

[image: View Controller Hierarchy]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the storyboard, try unchecking "Under Top Bars" in the TabBarController properties.

[image: View Controller Properties]